# Writing to a local file on hdfs in Spark from a non-Spark datastructure

Tags: scala, apache-spark, io

I have the following code:

```
def writeCSV(indexing: ListBuffer[Array[Int]], outputpath: String): Unit = {
    new PrintWriter(outputpath + "out.csv") {
      write("col1,col2,col3\n")

      for (entry <- indexing) {
        for (num <- entry) {
          write(num + "");
          if (num != entry(2)) write(",");
        }
        write("\n")
      }
      close
    }
```

Which does not work, because my Spark complains that the output path cannot be found. How would I be able to print this out from a regular datastructure (`ListBuffer[Array[Int]]`) to just a regular file in my Spark program? Do I need to map the `ListBuffer` to some Spark datastructure?

I understand this is not what you want to do normally, but this is more for use for debugging and will not be used in production code.

I am new to Spark and I am using Spark 1.6.0.

Comment: I am confused. What's exact meaning of `writing to a local file on hdfs` ??? You want to write a file on local path in executors or driver or on hdfs.

Comment: Write from driver to a local file on hdfs

Comment: It simply says that - whatever that output path is, Spark either can not see it or it does not exist. So if there is something wrong... then that is your output path.

Comment: Also... HDFS is a distributed file-system. So files on HDFS should not be referred as local files. The term `local file` generally refers to file on the local file-system of the computer running the program. So your file can either be called local or it can be called a HDFS file. It can not be referred as both like - `local file on hdfs`.

Comment: I see your concern, well I want to write a file on HDFS. The path is 100% correct, and I even tried creating an empty .csv file but it can still not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a file on HDFS, you would pass `InputStream` via `FileSystem` in `org.apache.hadoop.fs` package to `PrintWriter` constructor.

Example code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem,Path}
val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
new PrintWriter(fs.create(new Path(""))){
    write(...)
  }
```

Comment: I'm having a weird issue though. It creates the file on HDFS however the file is empty and nothing is written to it.

Comment: Did you close the write stream ?